# mysqli query error, not sure what's wrong

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a query here and not sure why the insert is failing... Here is the query and the error

```
INSERT INTO `tokyoStats` (stockName, open, high, low, close, change, stockFrom, stockParent, timestamp) VALUES ('topix', '1190.55', '1192.35', '1181.56', '1181.64', '-3.64', 'japan','topix','2013-09-18T01:00:05+09:00')
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change, stockFrom, stockParent, timestamp) VALUES ('topix', '1190.55', '1192.35'' at line 1

I'm not sure why this is wrong. I have other queries before this one that work perfectly fine.

Comment: the fields name you use have special meaning in MySQL you can either change them or surround them with `\`` (backticks)

Comment: For future code: You don't need to quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**change** is reserved word for mysql enclose it with backticks (`) and avoid this by changing column names, see this link for reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

```
INSERT INTO `tokyoStats` (`stockName`, `open`, `high`, `low`, `close`, `change`, `stockFrom`, `stockParent`, `timestamp`) 
VALUES 
('topix', '1190.55', '1192.35', '1181.56', '1181.64', '-3.64', 'japan','topix','2013-09-18T01:00:05+09:00')
```

Comment: MySQL has some weird reserved words :)

Comment: Well then... no wonder! I never knew that >.< Learn something new every day I suppose. Well, my column names are created using the associated key from an array, so I'll just change the names to something less vague. Thanks a lot man, I was steaming over this all day.

Comment: Sometimes I think that error handling in SQL databases shoud be completely re-designed. Error messages sometimes say nothing about acutal error and don't suggest anything. It feels like some ancient technology.

Comment: Use some text editor with syntax highlighting (notepad++ for example). It helps to catch bugs like this.

Comment: Once again, thanks guys. I'll probably forever remember this because of how much work I put into this project, only to be halted by some weird ass error that comes out of no where. Anyways, good awesomeness.

Comment: @tadman yea... it may suggest you what is the problem, if you remember all 226 reserved words from SQL manual. I think that error handling sucks anyway.

Comment: When in doubt, check the reserved keywords list. Usually the name you want to use is on there so you have to get creative.